# Golden gate adapter for kafka kafkahandler

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

```
ERROR [main] (DsHandler.java:293) - Unable to set property on handler 'kafkahandler' (oracle.goldengate.handler.kafka.KafkaHandler). Failed to set property: T
opicName:="test" (class: oracle.goldengate.handler.kafka.KafkaHandler).
oracle.goldengate.util.ConfigException: Failed to set property: TopicName:="test" (class: oracle.goldengate.handler.kafka.KafkaHandler).
    at oracle.goldengate.util.PropertyWrapper.setProperty(PropertyWrapper.java:365)
    at oracle.goldengate.util.PropertyWrapper.setProperties(PropertyWrapper.java:342)
    at oracle.goldengate.datasource.conf.DsHandler.initListener(DsHandler.java:289)
    at oracle.goldengate.datasource.conf.DsHandler.getDataSourceListener(DsHandler.java:259)
    at oracle.goldengate.datasource.factory.DataSourceFactory.getHandlers(DataSourceFactory.java:264)
    at oracle.goldengate.datasource.factory.DataSourceFactory.getDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at oracle.goldengate.datasource.DataSourceLauncher.<init>(DataSourceLauncher.java:161)
    at oracle.goldengate.datasource.UserExitMain.main(UserExitMain.java:108)
```

Comment: You've just posted an error. How about some context for what I presume is a question? What versions of the software? What's the contents of the relevant configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move data from Oracle Database to Kafka using Golden gate adapter Version 12.3.0.1.0

In new version there is no topicname

## The following resolves the topic name using the short table name

gg.handler.kafkahandler.topicMappingTemplate=test

In previous version we have
gg.handler.kafkahandler.topicName=test